# Swift NSUserDefaults not getting set

Tags: ios, swift, nsuserdefaults

I don't like to ask simple questions but today I am stumped. All I need to do is see if there is a value set in NSUserdefaults on app launch. If it is not then add a value. That's it. Every time I launch my app I get this as results

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool
    {

        let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var returnValue: [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("BGColorStr") as? [String]

        println("returnValue: \(returnValue) ...")

        if (returnValue == nil)
        {
            println("Value is nil")
            defaults.setObject("Default", forKey:"BGColorStr")
            defaults.synchronize()
        }
        else
        {
            println("Value is NOT nil")
        }


        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return true
    }

returnValue: nil ...
Value is nil
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you call `setObject` you're setting a string:

```
defaults.setObject("Default", forKey:"BGColorStr")
```

When you are retrieving the value, you are attempting to cast it into an optional array of strings:

```
var returnValue: [String]? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("BGColorStr") as? [String]
```

The `as?` operator sets `returnValue` to `nil` because the types don't match.

You're also using `var` instead of `let` when you don't need to, and not using the new `if let…` Swift syntax.

Try this instead: *(last updated for Swift 2 / Xcode 7 Beta 3)*

```
let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
let key = "BGColorStr"

if let storedValue = defaults.objectForKey(key) as? String {
    print("Value is NOT nil: \(storedValue)")
} else {
    print("Value is nil")
    defaults.setObject("Default", forKey:key)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

---

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you can encapsulate the logic into an `NSUserDefaults` extension:

```
extension NSUserDefaults {
    func objectForKey(defaultName: String, defaultValue: AnyObject) -> AnyObject {
        var obj = objectForKey(defaultName)

        if obj == nil {
            obj = defaultValue
            setObject(obj, forKey: defaultName)
        }

        return obj!
    }
}
```

Then to read a value:

```
let returnValue = NSUserDefaults
    .standardUserDefaults()
    .objectForKey("BGColorStr", defaultValue: "Default")

// returnValue is either the stored value or "Default"
```

Comment: One more question, when I get the value back what does the word "optional" mean and why its part of output? returnValue: Optional("Default")

Comment: It means `returnValue` may or may not be `nil`. `if let storedValue = returnValue` places the unwrapped value, if present, in `storedValue`.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like you're trying to set a string (`"Default`) in your `NSUserDefaults` and then retrieve an array of string (`[String]`).

Your return value will be of type `String` as opposed to `[String]`.

```
var returnValue = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("BGColorStr") as? String
```

Comment: The `: String?` is superfluous.